# Kubernetes run custom command in lifecycle

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm trying to deploy InfluxDB in kubernetes.

I can create all correctly, but I need to run this custom command below when the influx is up and running in the pod:

```
influx -username $INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER -password $INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD -execute "CREATE RETENTION POLICY metrics_yearly_rp ON $INFLUXDB_DB DURATION 52w REPLICATION 1"
```

or I can run a curl command below:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:8086/query -u $INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER:$INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD --data-urlencode "q=CREATE RETENTION POLICY metrics_yearly_rp ON $INFLUXDB_DB DURATION 52w REPLICATION 1"
```

I'm trying to configure commands in my yaml file, but without succeess.
this is my pod conf:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  labels:
    app: influxdb-monitoringdb
  name: influxdb-monitoringdb
  namespace: mon-grafana
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: influxdb-monitoringdb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: influxdb-monitoringdb
      containers:
        - name: influxdb
          image: influxdb:1.8.10
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          lifecycle:
            postStart:
              exec:
                command: ["/usr/bin/influx", "-username $(INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER) -password $(INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD) -execute \"CREATE RETENTION POLICY metrics_yearly_rp ON $(INFLUXDB_DB) DURATION 52w REPLICATION 1\""]
          env:
            - name: INFLUXDB_HTTP_AUTH_ENABLED
              value: "true"
            - name: INFLUXDB_DB
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: secrets
                  key: INFLUXDB_DB_monitoringdb
            - name: INFLUXDB_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: secrets
                  key: INFLUXDB_USER_monitoringdb
            - name: INFLUXDB_USER_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: secrets
                  key: INFLUXDB_USER_PASSWORD_monitoringdb
            - name: INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: secrets
                  key: INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER
            - name: INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: secrets
                  key: INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8086
              name: http-mondb
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/influxdb
              name: influxdb-monitoringdb-pv
            - mountPath: /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf
              name: configmap
              subPath: influxdb.conf
              readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: influxdb-monitoringdb-pv
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: influxdb-monitoringdb-pvc
        - name: configmap
          configMap:
            name: configmap
```

when I run `Kubectl apply -f myfile.yaml` the pod don't start

```
NAME                          READY   STATUS             RESTARTS        AGE     IP           NODE   NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
pod/influxdb-monitoringdb-0   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   6 (3m20s ago)   9m50s   10.1.77.28   k8s    <none>           <none>

$ kubectl logs influxdb-monitoringdb-0 -n mon-grafana
ts=2023-12-21T12:15:47.082261Z lvl=info msg="InfluxDB starting" log_id=0mF4h5YG000 version=1.8.10 branch=1.8 commit=688e697c51fd
ts=2023-12-21T12:15:47.082353Z lvl=info msg="Go runtime" log_id=0mF4h5YG000 version=go1.13.8 maxprocs=4

$ kubectl describe pods influxdb-monitoringdb-0 -n mon-grafana
...
Events:
  Type     Reason               Age                    From               Message
  ----     ------               ----                   ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled            4m48s                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned mon-grafana/influxdb-monitoringdb-0 to k8s
  Normal   Pulled               3m33s (x4 over 4m46s)  kubelet            Container image "influxdb:1.8.10" already present on machine
  Normal   Created              3m33s (x4 over 4m45s)  kubelet            Created container influxdb
  Normal   Started              3m32s (x4 over 4m44s)  kubelet            Started container influxdb
  Warning  FailedPostStartHook  3m32s (x4 over 4m44s)  kubelet            PostStartHook failed
  Normal   Killing              3m32s (x4 over 4m44s)  kubelet            FailedPostStartHook
  Warning  BackOff              3m31s (x5 over 4m12s)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container influxdb in pod influxdb-monitoringdb-0_mon-grafana(f9c64666-9ea2-4d7a-88e6-895ef6274bd2)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57592563/why-i-get-error-137-when-exec-lifecycle-hook-in-kubernetes-cronjob

Comment: If the `curl` command can be run from somewhere else (targeting the Service in front of this StatefulSet) then you could run it as a Job; if you were using Helm, you could label that Job as a post-install hook.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, you are trying to set retention policy on the bucket during a first deployment on influx.
There are a couple of ways to achieve it:

1. init `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` script;
2. kubernetes job;
3. any custom script that you can trigger outside of your deployment.

I will describe the first one, because I believe that is what you are looking for. If it's not the case, feel free to ask questions.

There is a thing called [Custom initialization scripts](https://hub.docker.com/_/influxdb) in influx. Basically, those are .sh scripts that you should put into the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` folder. During the influx db `setup` those would be executed.
Use volume mounting and config maps to put scripts inside the container and start a fresh influx. Don't forget to clean up persistent volumes, that are used for influx backup, otherwise init scripts will not run.

I will also attach an example of such script and helm setup, that I use.
volume description:

```
- name: influx-startup-script
      configMap:
        name: influx-startup-script
        defaultMode: 0744
        items:
        - key: init.sh
          path: init.sh
```

config map:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: influx-startup-script
  namespace: influxdb
data:
  init.sh: |-
{{ .Files.Get "files/init.sh" | indent 4}}
```

script itself in `chart/files/init.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e
bucket_id=$(influx bucket list -n bucket -o org | grep bucket | awk '{print $1}')
echo "Updating bucket with bucket_id: $bucket_id"
influx bucket update -i $bucket_id --retention 30d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply expose the InfluxDB port over a tunnel on your localhost using `kubectl port-forward` command.

That is, if you deployment has `service` definition.

```
kubectl port-forward svc/[influx service name] 8086:8086
```

Otherwise, you can even make a tunnel directly on the pod.

```
kubectl port-forward [influx pod name] 8086:8086
```

Then you should be able to use the curl from your localhost, as you expected.

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:8086/query -u $INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER:$INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD --data-urlencode "q=CREATE RETENTION POLICY metrics_yearly_rp ON $INFLUXDB_DB DURATION 52w REPLICATION 1"
```